# Can you please help me analyse my game?

Tags: analysis

```
[FEN ""] 
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2016.09.11"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Bright"]
[Black "Ogbe"]
[Result "1-0"]
[WhiteElo "?"]
[BlackElo "?"]
[ECO "C64"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 Bc5 4. Bxc6 dxc6 5. O-O Bg4 6. d3 Ne7 7. Bg5 f6     8. Be3 Bxe3 9. fxe3 O-O 10. Nc3 Ng6 11. h3 Be6 12. Qe2 Qd7 13. d4 b5 14. b3 Rad8 15. Rad1 exd4 16. exd4 Nf4 17. Qe3 Nxg2 18. Kxg2 Bxh3+ 19. Kh2 Bxf1 20. Rxf1 Qg4 21. Rg1 Qh5+ 22. Kg2 f5 23. e5 f4 24. Qe4 Rf5 25. Kf2 Qh3 26. Qxc6 g5 27. Qe6+ Kf8 28. Rxg5 1-0
```

I think after the knight sacrifice I should have doubled up my rooks and attack slowly. Please help me improve the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall:
The game was pretty drawish, leaning towards the black side, it was up to whose endgame was better. However, at the end, you took too much risks and lost due to that.

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2016.09.11"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Bright"]
[Black "Ogbe"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "C64"]

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5 Bc5 4.Bxc6 $6 {Minor comment: c3 and O-O are the moves that are studied, this throws away all advantage.} dxc6 5.O-O Bg4 6.d3 Ne7 7.Bg5 f6 8.Be3 Bxe3 9.fxe3 O-O 10.Nc3 Ng6 11.h3 Be6 12.Qe2 Qd7 13.d4 b5 14.b3 {Notice the weaknesses, save them and exploit them later in game. This is an example when you exploit them immediately[%draw full,c3,red][%draw full,b2,red] [%draw full,a3,red]} 14...Rad8 ( 14...b4 15.Na4 a5 16.c4 bxc3 17.Nxc3 )15.Rad1 exd4 $1 16.exd4 Nf4 17.Qe3 Nxg2 18.Kxg2 Bxh3+ { [%draw arrow,g2,f2,green]} 19.Kh2 Bxf1 20.Rxf1 Qg4 $2 {I suggest you start opening the board and exchanging pawns} ( 20...Qe6 {[%draw arrow,e6,a2,red][%draw arrow,a7,a4,red]} 21.Rg1 a5 22.Ne2 Rfe8 23.e5 fxe5 24.Qg5 Qe7 25.dxe5 Qxg5 26.Rxg5 Rd5 ) ( 20...Rfe8 21.Rg1 a5 22.Ne2 a4 ( 22...Qf7 {[%draw arrow,f7,a2,red][%draw arrow,a5,a4,red]} 23.Nf4 a4 24.Rg3 axb3 25.cxb3 Ra8 ) 23.bxa4 Ra8 24.axb5 Rxa2 25.bxc6 Qxc6 26.Qb3+ Qe6 ) 21.Rg1 Qh5+ 22.Kg2 f5 $2 {Defend. Be careful of counter-atacks} 23.e5 f4 24.Qe4 Rf5 $4 {White can easily win this [%draw full,c6,red][%draw full,c7,red][%draw full,a7,red][%draw full,h5,red] [%draw full,d8,red]} ( 24...b4 25.Ne2 Rd5 26.c4 Ra5 $14 ) 25.Kf2 Qh3 $18 {Pieces are too disconnected[%draw full,h3,red] [%draw full,c7,red] [%draw full,c6,red] [%draw full,a7,red] [%draw full,d8,red]} 26.Qxc6 g5 27.Qe6+ Kf8 28.Rxg5 1-0
```

Edit: SE somehow has errors when flipping it, I suggest not flipping it, or un-flip it at moments where there are arrows/highlighted squares(not much in this analysis)

Clearer PGN for users who can't render the board:

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5 Bc5 4.Bxc6 {?! Minor comment: c3 and O-O are the moves that are studied, this throws away all advantage.} 4...dxc6 5.O-O Bg4 6.d3 Ne7 7.Bg5 f6 8.Be3 Bxe3 9.fxe3 O-O 10.Nc3 Ng6 11.h3 Be6 12.Qe2 Qd7 13.d4 b5 14.b3 {Notice the weaknesses, save them and exploit them later in game. This is an example when you exploit them immediately}
14...Rad8

- ( 14...b4 15.Na4 a5 16.c4 bxc3 17.Nxc3 )

15.Rad1 exd4{!} 16.exd4 Nf4 17.Qe3 Nxg2 18.Kxg2 Bxh3+ 19.Kh2 Bxf1 20.Rxf1 Qg4{? I suggest you start opening the board and exchanging pawns}

- ( 20...Qe6 21.Rg1 a5 22.Ne2 Rfe8 23.e5 fxe5 24.Qg5 Qe7 25.dxe5 Qxg5 26.Rxg5 Rd5 )
- ( 20...Rfe8 21.Rg1 a5 22.Ne2 a4

  - ( 22...Qf7 23.Nf4 a4 24.Rg3 axb3 25.cxb3 Ra8 )

  23.bxa4 Ra8 24.axb5 Rxa2 25.bxc6 Qxc6 26.Qb3+ Qe6 )

21.Rg1 Qh5+ 22.Kg2 f5{? Defend. Be careful of counter-atacks} 23.e5 f4 24.Qe4 Rf5 {?? White can easily win this}

- ( 24...b4 25.Ne2 Rd5 26.c4 Ra5{+=} )

25.Kf2 Qh3{+- Pieces are too disconnected} 26.Qxc6 g5 27.Qe6+ Kf8 28.Rxg5 1-0

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't understand  the meaning of some terms in bracket "full red b2".

Comment: One small note: Black's 15th move hardly deserves a double exclamation mark. It isn't any bad, but it's not extraordinary either.

Comment: This is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Stockfish agrees with your assessment - you were overly aggressive.  Your `Ng2` sacrifice seems sound but by opening your King up you allowed White blunt your attack. After 10 minutes, Stockfish said:

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 Bc5 4. Bxc6 dxc6 5. O-O Bg4 6. d3 Ne7 7. Bg5 f6     8. Be3 Bxe3 9. fxe3 O-O 10. Nc3 Ng6 11. h3 Be6 12. Qe2 Qd7 13. d4 b5 14. b3 Rad8 15. Rad1 exd4 16. exd4 Nf4 17. Qe3 Nxg2 18. Kxg2 (18.Kxg2 Bxh3+ 19.Kf2 Bxf1 20.Rxf1 Rde8 21.Rh1 Rf7 22.Qd3 Qe7 23.Ke2 b4 24.e5 {Be careful, White is tricky} g5 25.Na4 fxe5 26.Nxe5 Rf4 27.Qc4+ Kg7 28.Qd3 Kg8 {with a more-or-less even if crazy game. Can White leverage his extra piece to overpower the opponents rook? With Queens on the board and the Kings exposed, a draw by repetition/perpetual seems likely unless great pains are taken to prevent it.}) Bxh3+ 19. Kh2 Bxf1 20. Rxf1 Qg4 21. Rg1 Qh5+ 22. Kg2 f5 {This is where the wheels start to come off the wagon. Instead `Rde1` preserves equality. White is now almost 2 pawns up.} 23. e5 f4 24. Qe4 Rf5 {Now Black is doomed; The deficit is about 400 centi-apwns. Black continues in dire straits with Qf5 instead.}  25. Kf2 Qh3 {Black is down about 600 centi-pawns after this move. `a6` was recommended.} 26. Qxc6 g5 {and that's that. There's no plausible hope. How much do you think White's magnificent f3 Knight is worth?} 27. Qe6+ Kf8 28. Rxg5 1-0
```

Answer (score 1):

16...Nf4 is the problem, regardless of what any engine tells you. The plan is wrong, there is no clear win for the sacrifice. I would have centralized both rooks (Rfe8), relocated the Be6 to g6 (Nf8/Bf7/Bg6), and attacked on the queenside where White's weaknesses are. White has problems on the e-file too if he is not careful.

2c.

Answer (score 1):

Your losing move was 23...f4. That allowed Qe4, gave White's queen a magnificent central square, from which she dominated the game. I like your chances up to that point, especially if you can exchange queens. A rook and two extra pawns (your h pawn is passed) is usually strong against two knights. Therefore, you should have  centralized your queen at d6 and moved the passed h pawn rather than aiming for a direct attack against the king.

Your second worst move (earlier) was 13... b5, which weakened your c5 pawn, which the Q on e4 was able to take. But this would not have been a problem if you had not allowed her to get to e4 in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 { Ruy Lopez } 3...Bc5 { (delayed) Classical variation } 4. Bxc6 { Exchange Variation, perhaps premature as Black hasn't given up anything to get the bishop. } (3. c3 { to prevent ...Nd4, a useful move to force a trade } ) 4...dxc6 { I think Black is equal, with the two bishops and no noticeable weaknesses. } 5. O-O Bg4 ( 5...Qd6 { should be good, staying flexible with Bc8, though Nb1-d2-c4 } ) ( 5...Qf6 { aiming for the king-side might be good if it can later move safely to g6 without loss of pawn e5 } ) 6. d3 Ne7 7. Bg5 { a waste of time as ...f6 was good for Black } 7...f6 8. Be3 Bxe3 9. fxe3 O-O ( 9...Qd7 { !? keeping the option of ...O-O-O to stay free for offense on the king-side } ) 10. Nc3 Ng6 ( 10...c5 { not the king-side attack, but intending ...c6 to hold squares d4 and d5, but also to consider ...Ne7-c6 } ) 11. h3 Be6 12. Qe2 Qd7 { Can you imagine how happy Black would be if he could follow-u with ...O-O-O? The king-side could go fully on the offense. } 13. d4 b5 { The position is pretty level. It's hard to generate offense anywhere. Threatening ...Bc4 is fine. Threatening ...b4 to disrupt White is also fine. Simply ...Rad8 or ...b6 may be best. } 14. b3 Rad8 15. Rad1 exd4 16. exd4 Nf4 {?} ( 16...Rfe8 { to put pressure on the weak central pawns makes more sense than to go after the king-side since the Black rooks can't help in that fight } ) 17. Qe3 Nxg2 18. Kxg2 Bxh3+ 19. Kh2 Bxf1 20. Rxf1 Qg4 21. Rg1 Qh5+ 22. Kg2 f5 23. e5 f4 24. Qe4 { +/- The king is safe enough and White's pieces are working together much better than Black's. } 24...Rf5 25. Kf2 Qh3 26. Qxc6 g5 27. Qe6+ Kf8 28. Rxg5 { White wasn't playing very aggressively, but the position didn't offer much after his early Bxc6. Black could have gotten more by aiming for an unbalanced position with ...Qd7, ...O-O-O. Then Black over-reached with the Nxg2 sac and it cost the game. } 1-0